# schema.org deserialize in Java

Tags: java, gson, schema.org

I am trying to deserialize schema.org's objects but every time I face a wall of complexity. I'm not sure if it's my fault or no one ever did this. I tried several schema.org's item and all of them sooner or later encounter the same issue (for obvious reasons actually). The problem lies on property like "Author". For example a cooking recipe has an author. Schema.org/Recipe says that the author can be an a Person or an Organisation. Both are schema.org's objects.

Until now it's easy. I get a schema for a Recipe and pass it to [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) and obtain my classes.
Then with Gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Recipe recipe = gson.fromJson(myString,Recipe.class);
```

myString is the json-ld I used to generate the Recipe classes. Once I try to download some more recipes from the web, I immediately encounter schemas where the Author is not a schema.org item, but a simple String. From this point on I am blocked. The parser is stuck, exactly like google's schemaorg-java parser.

I did read that some people modify the class to have authors as Object and then modify the getter and setters. A deserializer should be made for the whole Recipe class, but it must behave differently only for Author (and other similar Parameters.

Isn't there an easier way to deserialize schema.org in java? Am I googling wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GSON you'll need to create custom deserialisers. Your best bet is to read the type of the author value and if it is a string create a custom Author POJO with the name set as the string.

You've chosen a difficult language to implement this parser. Strongly typed languages are going to have a tough time deserialising data from a loosely typed language.

On top of that schema.org isn't well defined. Plus people will screw up their schema.org markup. It's up to you to decide how you'll handle it. Do you reject all data that doesn't conform exactly to the data or do you try to coerce the data?

I'm curious what you're working on. Is it a web service?

Comment: I am crawling the web for Items that have already a definition in order to be able to find other Items and define them automatically. I gave up with java and now I'm doing it in python. I might go back to java for the ML part, not sure.

Comment: TBH I think JavaScript may be a better choice. JSON itself comes from JS.